# Can I dissolve eggshells in vinegar, and use the vinegar in a dish?

Tags: eggs, vinegar, nutrient-composition

Are there other dishes where this is done to increase the bio-availablity of calcium in a dish, such as pork knuckle vinegar stew, which is considered a post-partum dish in Cantonese style cooking.

https://www.thefooddictator.com/the-hirshon-chinese-black-vinegar-pork-trotter-post-partum-stew-%E7%8C%AA%E8%84%9A%E9%86%8B/

Comment: Uh.... this is borderline at best. We will not answer dietary questions, so the first part is off topic. And asking for suitable dishes is opinion-based, which is also off-topic here. So what remains is the part for which vinegar will work best. Could you please [edit] your post?

Comment: yes, you can do that if you wish, but I wouldn't count on the calcium being bio-available.

Comment: And the story of how (the majority of) the stew is shared with friends and family won’t help the mother recuperate, so your link seems to have contradicting claims.

Comment: Both calcium acetate and calcium hydroxide are pretty soluble in water. It should go into the stomach just fine. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_acetate

Comment: @Stephie Chinese cultures have an interesting array of post-partum dishes, served to the mother during their 1 month "confinement period" - or "sitting the moon" if translated. These stews are made in bulk by the parent and forced upon the mother, who are often soon sick of eating this thick, strong tasting and greasy dish day after day and so friends and family are called in to help handle leftovers. Here's another similar recipe. https://thewoksoflife.com/cantonese-pork-knuckles-ginger-vinegar/

Comment: To expand @dandavis' comment, bioavailibility of Ca²⁺ depends on a number of factors, and any of them could be the bottleneck. I gather that in developing countries and with some vegetarian diets, the Ca in the food is a typical bottleneck: these are diets rich in phytate or oxalate which are anions that build unsoluble calcium salts (same for Fe²⁺). In that case, making sure there is more Ca²⁺ in the food helps. OTOH, here in Germany, lack of vitamin D is a typical bottleneck - and if that's the problem, more Ca²⁺ in the food doesn't help. Moreover, if it's not about bioavailability of Ca²⁺..

Comment: ... but about bone growth/avoiding bone loss, then in addition mechanical stimulus is needed. And I'm sure this is far from comprehensive....

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX of course bone growth also requires phosphorous and plenty of protein (as does bone healing which is why I've about this, having broken a few last year).  So the interaction with phosphate uptake gets even more complex.

Answer (score 5):

Addressing the *food chemistry* aspect:

Vinegar (acetic acid) reacts with calcium carbonate in the eggshells to make [calcium acetate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_acetate) (Wikipedia), as in the [naked egg experiment](https://www.scienceofcooking.com/eggs/naked-egg-experiment.html).  Calcium acetate can be used, among other things, to [gel alcohol](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/41094/17347); in food it can be used to coagulate tofu as well as having a stabilising effect.  There's a chance it will act as a thickener <s>depending on quantity</s> depending on what else is present in the sauce; the chemistry is [quite intersting](https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/University_of_California_Davis/UCDemos/CA_(California)_Snowball).

This chemical reaction means you won't have as much acidity left in the vinegar as when you started but the additional flavour of all but the most refined vinegars should survive, so you can choose one that matches the other ingredients.  For a Chinese-inspired dish, rice vinegar would be an obvious choice.  It's not clear to me whether the calcium acetate itself would have a flavour, pleasant or otherwise

I can't comment on the nutritional aspect, but will just add a note of caution from a *food safety* point of view (actually 2):

Calcium acetate has a [medicinal use](https://www.mayoclinic.org/drugs-supplements/calcium-acetate-oral-route/description/drg-20062494) and making and consuming medicinal compounds at home can't be assumed to be safe. In this case it treats cases of excess blood phosphate by preventing the absorption of phosphate in food; how much you'd consume, and how this relates to the levels seen in foods/medicines  are not things we can help with.

If you wished to make a vinegar-preserved food (rather different to the example you've added since I started writing this) you'd have to take into account the fact that you've neutralised  much of the acid in the vinegar, and therefore much of it's preserving power.

Comment: The question changed while I was answering it, but I think I've managed to make the answer on topic, even if the question is borderline

Comment: Thank you Chris, for the food chemistry and safety aspect.

Comment: Of course, substances with medicinal properties cannot automatically be assumed to be safe. Calcium acetate however is quite harmless - the exception being persons who should avoid calcium-rich food, but the question basically precludes that. Calcium acetate is food additive E 263 and as such does not have a specific restriction on the quantity added (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calciumacetat). The bioavailability of the calcium (and in consequence also phosphate) is also no different from eating the egg shell as finely ground powder (other than this will lead to burping).

Comment: @cbeleites English Wikipedia lacked the note about no upper limit, but I deliberately didn't look for an authoritative source as I felt I'd then need get into a discussion about dose and phosphate uptake. Your comment is helpful though (and I can just about make sense of the German Wikipedia article you linked to)